# execute of dynamic sql does not set found in psql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I execute an sql using dynamic sql in a trigger as the trigger will run across multiple tables. The sql will select from a table and check if there are results do nothing if no results insert into a table. it works  wit the first psql select but the found variable is true even though it is empty

```
 create function test() returns trigger $Body$
 execute 'select * from ' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME) || '_table1 where condition';

 if not found then
 insert into x values(anything);
 end if;

execute 'select * from ' || quote_indent(TG_TABLE_NAME) || '_table2 where condition';

if not found then
insert into y values (values);
end if;
......
```

the second condition i am sure it produces no result but found is still true any solution to have this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `get diagnostics` instead:

```
...
declare
    rcount int;
begin
    execute 'select * from some_table';
    get diagnostics rcount = row_count;
    if rcount = 0 then
        ...
```

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

> Note in particular that EXECUTE changes the output of GET DIAGNOSTICS, but does not change FOUND.